# Unexpected fallthrough in MDX IIF statement for age buckets

Tags: scope, mdx, bucket, iif

I’m fairly new to the BI field and have been taking my first steps with OLAP, Cubes, and MDX.

Right now, I am stuck with a seemingly trivial problem that I can’t get my head around and would very much like to ask for advice.

I want to organize inventory items in age buckets, according to their age in days, between the date the item was last sold and a specified Reporting Date. I created an Age Bucket dimension for this purpose, with buckets [0..6] months, [6..12] months, etc.

Then, I created a calculated measure, that I only want to set, per item, for the matching Age Bucket (0, 1, 2, 3, 4), based on the ItemAgeSales in days, as follows:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[MEASURES].[TEST] AS NULL,
VISIBLE = 1, ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'Item Transaction';

SCOPE(MEASURES.[TEST]);
(STRTOMEMBER("[Age Bucket].[Age Bucket].&[" +
    IIF( [MEASURES].[ItemAgeSales] >= 730 , "4",
        IIF([MEASURES].[ItemAgeSales] >= 548 , "3",
            IIF([MEASURES].[ItemAgeSales] >= 365 , "2",
                IIF([MEASURES].[ItemAgeSales] >= 183 , "1", "0"
                )//1,0
            )//2
        )//3
    )//4
+ "]")
)
= [MEASURES].[ItemAgeSales];
END SCOPE;
```

The problem with above script is that, regardless of the value of the ItemAgeSales measure for an item, the item always falls through to the bucket ‘0’ (i.e. [0..6] months) and it is not clear to me why exactly this is the case.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong or have some helpful thoughts on this or a hint towards solving the problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[Image of Cube Browser showing that ItemAgeSales is always set for the 0..6 Age Bucket, instead for the correct bucket.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPETk.png)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that because the way the MDX is written the `IIF` function is evaluated when a user connects to the cube, not in the context of any query or report or filter. Anything to the left of the equals sign or the parameter to the `SCOPE` statement is evaluated upon connection. Everything to the right is evaluated at query time.

I assume that you want the `IIF` statement to depend on any filters a report contains (like filtering by the Item dimension or whatever). I would change the MDX to...

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[MEASURES].[TEST] AS NULL,
VISIBLE = 1, ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'Item Transaction';

SCOPE(MEASURES.[TEST]);
  [Age Bucket].[Age Bucket].&[4] = IIF([MEASURES].[ItemAgeSales] >= 730 , [MEASURES].[ItemAgeSales], NULL);
  [Age Bucket].[Age Bucket].&[3] = IIF([MEASURES].[ItemAgeSales] >= 548 and [MEASURES].[ItemAgeSales] < 730, [MEASURES].[ItemAgeSales], NULL);
  [Age Bucket].[Age Bucket].&[2] = IIF([MEASURES].[ItemAgeSales] >= 365 and [MEASURES].[ItemAgeSales] < 548, [MEASURES].[ItemAgeSales], NULL);
  [Age Bucket].[Age Bucket].&[1] = IIF([MEASURES].[ItemAgeSales] >= 183 and [MEASURES].[ItemAgeSales] < 365, [MEASURES].[ItemAgeSales], NULL);
  [Age Bucket].[Age Bucket].&[0] = IIF([MEASURES].[ItemAgeSales] < 183, [MEASURES].[ItemAgeSales], NULL);
END SCOPE;
```